# Using indexedDB, I have a event listener which calls a function when a div is clicked, but it doesn't work

Tags: javascript, dom, event-listener

I have this function:

```js
function event_erase_nota (){
       
    document.addEventListener('click', (e)=> {
    let elementParent = e.target.parentNode;
        
        if (elementParent.className == 'delete'){
            id = elementParent.parentNode.id;
            
            console.log(id) 
            erase_nota(id)
       }
    })
}
event_erase_nota()
```

Detect when a div with the class 'delete' is clicked and call the function erase_nota that is on other archive.

```js
function erase_nota (id) {
    const request = indexedDB.open("noto", 1);
    
    request.onsuccess = (event) => {
        var db = event.target.result;
        
        let trx = db.transaction("nota", "readwrite");
        let request = trx.objectStore("nota").delete(id);
        
        trx.oncomplete = function () {
            console.log("Nota eliminada")
            
            db.close();
        }
    }
}
```

But the note stores in the data base doesn't get erased!
When I call the function 'erase_nota(someId)' in the console works fine.

What's wrong?

Comment: And does it show you that the element was clicked? Try add on top of your event handler: `console.log(e.target.parentNode.className);`

Comment: @vanowm yes it show it was clicked, the function gets the Id propperly, and calls the secend function, erase_nota.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the type of the variable id:

```js
if (elementParent.className == 'delete'){
            id = elementParent.parentNode.id;
            
            console.log(id) 
            erase_nota(id) //
```

I checked the typeof id and was a string, so I convert it to Number,

```
if (elementParent.className == 'delete'){
            id = elementParent.parentNode.id;
            
            console.log(id) 
            erase_nota(Number(id))
```

Now it works!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```java
let trx = db.transaction(["nota"], "readwrite");
```

Comment: @Spectric it did not work.

Comment: @CArlosR I'm not the answerer - I edited the answer. Did you mean to notify 'A User'?